# Using Ruta, get a data present in next line of annotated keyword

Tags: uima, ruta

How to get data below/above annotated keyword present in other line? I am able to annotate keyword but not able to get information

Sample text:

```
Underwriter's Name    Appraiser's Name          Appraisal Company Name
Alice Wheaton Cooper  Bruce Banner               Stark Industries
```

Code

```
TYPESYSTEM utils.PlainTextTypeSystem;
ENGINE utils.PlainTextAnnotator;

EXEC(PlainTextAnnotator, {Line});
ADDRETAINTYPE(WS);
Line{->TRIM(WS)};
REMOVERETAINTYPE(WS);
Document{->FILTERTYPE(SPECIAL)};

DECLARE UnderWriterKeyword, NameKeyword, UnderWriterNameKeyword;
DECLARE UnderWriterName(String label, String value);

CW{REGEXP("\\bUnderwriter") -> UnderWriterKeyword};
CW{REGEXP("Name")->NameKeyword};
(UnderWriterKeyword SW NameKeyword){->UnderWriterNameKeyword};
ADDRETAINTYPE(SPACE);
Line{CONTAINS(UnderWriterNameKeyword)} Line -> {
    (CW SPACE)+ {-> MARK(UnderWriterName)};
    };
REMOVERETAINTYPE(SPACE)
```

Expected Output :

```
Underwriter's Name: Alice Wheaton Cooper    
Appraiser's Name: Bruce Banner
Appraisal Company Name: Stark Industries
```

Please suggest if it is possible in RUTA ? If true, how to get data?

Comment: Which options did you try so far? *Hint:* the `BLOCK` statement restricts your matching window to the `Line` which `CONTAINS(UserName)`.

Comment: I don't know how to to shift one line next once this condition is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TYPESYSTEM utils.PlainTextTypeSystem;
ENGINE utils.PlainTextAnnotator;

DECLARE Header;
DECLARE ColumnDelimiter;
DECLARE Cell(INT column);

DECLARE Keyword (STRING label);
DECLARE Keyword UnderWriterNameKeyword, AppraiserNameLicenseKeyword,
AppraisalCompanyNameKeyword;

"Underwriter's Name" -> UnderWriterNameKeyword ( "label" = "UnderWriter
Name");
"Appraiser's Name/License" -> AppraiserNameLicenseKeyword ( "label" =
"Appraiser Name");
"Appraisal Company Name" -> AppraisalCompanyNameKeyword ( "label" =
"Appraisal Company Name");

DECLARE Entry(Keyword keyword);

EXEC(PlainTextAnnotator, {Line,Paragraph});

ADDRETAINTYPE(WS);
Line{->TRIM(WS)};
Paragraph{->TRIM(WS)};

SPACE[3,100]{-PARTOF(ColumnDelimiter) -> ColumnDelimiter};
Line -> {ANY+{-PARTOF(Cell),-PARTOF(ColumnDelimiter) -> Cell};};
REMOVERETAINTYPE(WS);

INT index = 0;
BLOCK(structure) Line{}{
    ASSIGN(index, 0);
    Line{STARTSWITH(Paragraph) -> Header};
    c:Cell{-> c.column = index, index = index + 1};
}

Header<-{hc:Cell{hc.column == c.column}<-{k:Keyword;};}
    # c:@Cell{-PARTOF(Header) -> e:Entry, e.keyword = k};

DECLARE Entity (STRING label, STRING value);
DECLARE Entity UnderWriterName, AppraiserNameLicense, AppraisalCompanyName;

FOREACH(entry) Entry{}{
    entry{ -> CREATE(UnderWriterName, "label" = k.label, "value" =
entry.ct)}<-{k:entry.keyword{PARTOF(UnderWriterNameKeyword)};};
    entry{ -> CREATE(AppraiserNameLicense, "label" = k.label, "value" =
entry.ct)}<-{k:entry.keyword{PARTOF(AppraiserNameLicenseKeyword)};};
    entry{ -> CREATE(AppraisalCompanyName, "label" = k.label, "value" =
entry.ct)}<-{k:entry.keyword{PARTOF(AppraisalCompanyNameKeyword)};};
}
```

The most important rule is the following:

```
Header<-{hc:Cell{hc.column == c.column}<-{k:Keyword;};}
    # c:@Cell{-PARTOF(Header) -> e:Entry, e.keyword = k};
```

It contains three rule element, `Header`,`#` and `Cell`, and works this way:

- The rule starts to match with the `Cell` rule element because it is tagged as anchor with `@`.
- This rule element matches on all `Cell` annotations that or not part of a `Header` annotation. It starts with the first `Cell` annotation that fulfills this condition and calls it "c".
- The next rule element is `#` which matches until the next rule element is able to match.
- The next rule element matches on a `Header` annotation if the inlined rule is able to match within the span of the `Header` annotation. The inlined rule matches on the `Cell` annotations remembered as "hc" within this span that have the same value for the feature `column`. The match is successful, if it contains a `Keyword` remembered as "k".
- If these three rule elements matched successfully, then the actions are applied.
- The first action creates an `Entry` annotation called "e" on the span of the `Cell` annotation.
- The second action assigns the keyword to the `Entry` feature `keyword`.

As a summary, the rule creates an `Entry` annotation for each `Cell` annotation that is not part of the header and assigns the header keyword of the corresponding column in order to define the type of the entry.

Comment: thanks Peter.I am not able to understand part of code. Please elaborate what is happening here `Header<-{hc:Cell{hc.column == c.column}<-{k:Keyword;};}
    # c:@Cell{-PARTOF(Header) -> e:Entry, e.keyword = k};`

Comment: I extened the answer

Comment: Can we limit how many times rule element should match ? `# c:@Cell{-PARTOF(Header) -> e:Entry, e.keyword = k};`. Here `#` matches n times. Can we restrict it(say 3 times) ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [inlined rules](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.blocks.block) in Ruta.

You could define your condition for one line and annotate the needed info inside the next one:

```
Line{CONTAINS(UserName)} Line -> { //your logic here };
```

Comment: data :`Underwriter's Name          Appraiser's Name/License          Appraisal CompanyName
Alice Wheaton               Bruce Banner                      Stark Industries`.  I added following logic `n:CW[1,3]{-> CREATE(UnderWriterName, "label"="UnderWriter Name", "value"=n.ct)};`, but it fetches all text which matches this condition. How can I ask it to stop looking if two many spaces are in between? inlined rules?

Comment: You can retain the whitespaces with `ADDRETAINTYPE(SPACE)` and allow for just one in between, in your rule. Don't forget to filter them out afterwards.

Comment: I tried this `(CW SPACE CW) {-> MARK(UnderWriterName, 1,3)}`. It marks all three names - Alice Wheaton, Bruce Banner, Stark Industries. Is there a way I can mark just first once or get first marked instance?

Comment: If I change name to "Alice Wheaton Cooper", then above mentioned query fails as I am just marking first two words. Is there a way if more than one spaces are present, I can mark previously traversed words ? Tried something like this `(CW SPACE CW SPACE CW SPACE SPACE) {-> MARK(UnderWriterName, 1,3,5)};` , but doesn't appear to me as right way?

Comment: is there a way of indexing? Lets say `UnderWriter's Name` appear in offset 0-18 in line 1. Can we check same index values in next line for our data? I understand offset are continous stream of numbers for whole document, not line by line.

Comment: First of all, the indexes `1,3,5` in your `MARK` action do something else than you think they do. They are used to set the span by taking certain rule elements into account (see [documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.actions.mark)).

Comment: Secondly, I don't understand how your data is structured (it is just a line). Try to update your question with the new data format.

Comment: Yes, you could use the wide span of spaces as a separator for the names: `(CW SPACE CW){-> CREATE(UnderWriterName)} SPACE[5,100] CW`. However, this is not the most robust solution.

Comment: is there a way to move one line above current line position? Lets say if I have data above annotated keyword and that is only annotated keyword present in document.

Comment: Yes, you could say: `Line{//your conditions/actions on this line} Line{CONTAINS(YourKeyword)};`

Comment: Can we specific lines to look for keyword to RUTA? I mean like first 20 lines or last 20 lines or it is always top to bottom approach

Comment: It always starts at the beginning of the document, in an ascending order of the anotation's indexes. You can easily though, skip the irrelevant `Line` annotations: `Line[20,20] Line{ // this is line 21};`. Alternatively, you could play around wtih the visibility of the irrelevant annotations with `ADDRETAINTYPE(YourType)` and `REMOVERETAINTYPE(YourType)`